# Attaching $fields to $_FILES

Tags: php, file

If I have the following associative array:

```
$fields = [                                 //store empty fields
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],     
    'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
    'location' => $_POST['location'],
    'proposal' => $_POST['proposal'] //--------------> proposal = attachment file
];
```

How do I use them for `$_FILES["attachment"]["name"]` ?

My plan is to check whether the proposal is pdf, docx, or .doc

here is what I did so far:

```
        if(!empty($_FILES[$fields['proposal']]['name']) ){
            //variables
            $fileName = $_FILES[$fields['proposal']]['name'];
            $tempName = $_FILES[$fields['proposal']]['tmp_name'];
            $fileType = $_FILES[$fields['proposal']]['type'];

            //get the extension of the file
            $base = basename($fileName);
            $extension = substr($base, strlen($base)-4, strlen($base));

            //only these file types will be allowed
            $allowedExtension = array(".doc", ".pdf", "docx");

            //check that this file type is allowed
            if (in_array($extension, $allowedExtension)) {


            }else {
            $errors['proposal'] = 'You can only upload pdf files';                  

            } 
        }
```

Comment: you can't, really. $_FILES is built/populated automatically by PHP for you. There's **NO** reason to add extra fields in there. And note that figuring out file types by extension is extremely unreliable. `ren nastyvirus.exe resume.pdf` and boom goes the laughable "securitY" check you have.

Comment: Ah why isn't the `type` field good enough for you? That contains the mime-type sent by the user, which would theoretically already be `application/pdf` or whatever anyways.